# Does anyone know how to download TRMM 3B42 time series data?

Tags: r, download, ftp

I'm trying to download TRMM 3B42 3-hour binary data for a given time span from this [NASA FTP server](ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/Gridded/3B42_V7/).

There is an excellent code made by Florian Detsch to download the daily product (here is the link: https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/blob/master/R/downloadTRMM.R) included in the GitHub-only **Rsenal** package. Unfortunately it is not working for the 3-hour data.

I changed the code:

```
downloadTRMM <- function(begin, end, dsn = ".", format = "%Y-%m-%d.%H") {

  ## transform 'begin' and 'end' to 'Date' object if necessary
  if (!class(begin) == "Date")
    begin <- as.Date(begin, format = format)

  if (!class(end) == "Date")
    end <- as.Date(end, format = format)

  ## trmm ftp server
  ch_url <-"ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/Gridded/3B42_V7/"

  ## loop over daily sequence
  ls_fls_out <- lapply(seq(begin, end, 1), function(i) {

    # year and julian day (name of the corresponding folder)
    tmp_ch_yr <- strftime(i, format = "%Y%m")
    #tmp_ch_dy <- strftime(i, format = "%j")

    # trmm date format
    tmp_dt <- strftime(i+1, format = "%Y%m%d.%H")

    # list files available on server
    tmp_ch_url <- paste(ch_url, tmp_ch_yr, "", sep = "/")

    tmp_ch_fls <- tmp_ch_fls_out <- character(2L)
    for (j in 1:2) {
      tmp_ch_fls[j] <- paste0("3B42.", tmp_dt, "z.7.precipitation", 
                              ifelse(j == 1, ".bin"))

      tmp_ch_fls[j] <- paste(tmp_ch_url, tmp_ch_fls[j], sep = "/")
      tmp_ch_fls_out[j] <- paste(dsn, basename(tmp_ch_fls[j]), sep = "/")

      download.file(tmp_ch_fls[j], tmp_ch_fls_out[j], mode = "wb")
    }

    # return data frame with *.bin and *.xml filenames
    tmp_id_xml <- grep("xml", tmp_ch_fls_out)
    data.frame(bin = tmp_ch_fls_out[-tmp_id_xml], 
               xml = tmp_ch_fls_out[tmp_id_xml], 
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  })

  ## join and return names of processed files
  ch_fls_out <- do.call("rbind",ls_fls_out)
  return(ch_fls_out)
}

getwd()

setwd("C:/Users/joaoreis/Documents/Bases_Geograficas/trmm_3h/")

fls_trmm <- downloadTRMM(begin = "2008-01-01.00", end = "2008-01-05.00")
fls_trmm
```

But I get the following error:

> trying URL
>   'ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/Gridded/3B42_V7//200801//3B42.20080102.00z.7.precipitation.bin'
>   Error in download.file(tmp_ch_fls[j], tmp_ch_fls_out[j], mode = "wb")
>   :    cannot open URL
>   'ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/Gridded/3B42_V7//200801//3B42.20080102.00z.7.precipitation.bin'
>   In addition: Warning message: In download.file(tmp_ch_fls[j],
>   tmp_ch_fls_out[j], mode = "wb") :   InternetOpenUrl failed: '' Called
>   from: download.file(tmp_ch_fls[j], tmp_ch_fls_out[j], mode = "wb")

Does anyone know how to fix it using R?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look too difficult to modify the original code to accommodate 3-hour data. What have you tried so far? What errors did you get?

Comment: @thecatalyst, there are some differences in how the data are stored. For example the file name, one uses julian day ([daily data](ftp://disc3.nascom.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B42_daily/2008/001/)) and the other uses one folder for each month of the year to store the data file ([3-hour data](ftp://disc2.nascom.nasa.gov/data/TRMM/Gridded/3B42_V7/)). I think that is why does not work. I'm trying to solve, but I 'm not able to do much thing in R yet, I just usually use raster package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of commit [909f98a](https://github.com/environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal/commit/909f98ae18903d440c82d4a04d66e1af93298fde#diff-8863bddfa9490cf66fa0066e619729f6), I have enabled the automated retrieval of 3-hourly data from [ftp://disc3.nascom.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/TRMM_L3](ftp://disc3.nascom.nasa.gov/data/s4pa/TRMM_L3/TRMM_3B42/). Make sure you have the latest version of **Rsenal** installed using

```
devtools::install_github("environmentalinformatics-marburg/Rsenal")
```

and then have a look at the examples in `?downloadTRMM`. For now, the function supports both `character` (requires 'format' argument passed on to `strptime`) and `POSIXlt` input. For example, something like

```
downloadTRMM(begin = "2015-01-01 12:00", end = "2015-01-03 12:00", 
             type = "3-hourly", format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

to download 3-hourly data from 1-3 January 2015 (noon to noon) should now work just fine.

Note that in contrast to the FTP server you mentioned, the data comes in .HDF format and a `rasterize` method has not been implemented so far, meaning that you have to deal with the container files yourself. I'll try to figure out something more convenient soon regarding the automated rasterization of the data.

Comment: I'm late, but I didn't forget to thanks. Your Rsenal package helped a lot. I mentioned the other FTP link because I think it is easier to work with .bin data than .hdf in R. But it's ok. I'm going to wait and follow the development (automated rasterization) of the package. Thanks @fdetsch !